# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Receiving this error.

> 2013-02-28 16:19:49.628 VLC[1416:907] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

This is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // This will mark crashy files
    [[MLMediaLibrary sharedMediaLibrary] applicationWillStart];

    [_window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [_window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];


    NSURL * urlToOpen = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    urlToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://192.168.4.123"];

    if (urlToOpen != nil) {
        // We were started to open a given URL
        MVLCMovieViewController * movieViewController = [[MVLCMovieViewController alloc] init];
        movieViewController.url = urlToOpen;

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:movieViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        [movieViewController release];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized your `navigationController` with `UIViewController` before adding to `window`.

Try it like:

```
YourViewController *object_yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController"
                                                                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navObject_vc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:object_yvc];
```